# installing ta-lib with pipenv return with an error

Tags: pipenv, ta-lib

I am trying to install ta-lib with pipenv. I have managed to install it with pip (pip3) by download the ta-lib sources, compile and install them but when trying to do it with pipenv it fails. I am getting the next error:

```
"/tmp/pip-install-4fmnztw8/talib/setup.py", line 20, in run', '        
raise Exception("You probably meant to install and run ta-lib")', '
Exception: You probably meant to install and run ta-lib', '    
----------------------------------------', 
'ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:...
```

"You probably meant to install and run ta-lib" (no-kidding)... someone managed to install it with pipenv ?

using ubutnu 18 on windows wsl with python 3.6.8

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install it by using the exact command from [docs](http://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/install.html)

```sh
pipenv install TA-Lib
```

Before executing you need to have [TA-Lib](http://ta-lib.org/hdr_dw.html) already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, but TLDR; see the docker solution at the bottom.

I'm a Windows 10 user but this might help.
Here is a solution by first installing with Anaconda:

## Download and install Anaconda

https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual

## Create a conda environment with Python 3.5

(You could call myenv whatever you want, like ta-lib for example.)

`conda create -n myenv python=3.5`

## Activate the conda environment (You could call myenv whatever you want, like ta-lib for example.)

`conda activate myenv`

## Install this ta-lib anaconda package:

https://anaconda.org/Quantopian/ta-lib

`conda install -c quantopian ta-lib`

## Install pipenv in conda environment

`pip install pipenv`

## Here comes the sort of workaround:

https://pipenv-searchable.readthedocs.io/advanced.html#pipenv-and-conda

`pipenv --python=/path/to/anaconda/python --site-packages`

for example, on Windows 10, I used this command, from within my conda ta-lib environment which again has Python 3.5:

`pipenv --python 3.5=C:\Users\johnj\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python--site-packages`

Boom, now you have a pipenv with ta-lib. However, is it useful? It doesn't seem like having ta-lib in this virtual environment is helpful, because in my short experience having ta-lib in the pipfile or requirements text doesn't enable it to be replicated, like in a docker file.

Since you're on Linux, you might find the following solution of this Linux user's docker image on AWS Lambda more helpful, useful, and interesting:

https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/issues/225

Hope this helps!